# Can a witness answer a yes/no question with "Sure"?

Tags: trial

When a witness is presented with a yes or no question on cross-examination, is answering "sure" an equivalent answer to "yes"? Specifically, could it be viewed by a jury that a witness answering "sure" is not as strong of an affirmative answer to the question as "yes" would be?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This is very common.

A persnickety lawyer or judge could insist on an actual "yes," but generally speaking, everyone expects witnesses to talk like normal people.

Comment: Some statements like unh-unh, or uh-huh, can be unclear in a written transcript even if they are clear from intonation and timing at the time. In those circumstances, a good lawyer asks a follow up question to make the record clear, obtaining the assistance of the judge if necessary. Leading questions can be allowed to clarify what answer a witness gave in that situation even if the lawyer is not generally allowed to ask that witness leading questions.

Comment: +1 for the use of "persnickety"